# Windows security updates for server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have been trying to research this and can't seem to find an answer. I will try to be as detailed as possible. I ran a Nessus scan on a few windows server 2012 r2. A specific security update is not installed and Nessus recommends to install it. When I go to the microsoft update catalog I type in for example: KBxxxxxxx and it brings up the update. It also brings the update for windows 8.1. However, the only one I want is the security update for 2012 r2. There are 3 different links for the update 2 for windows 8.1 and 1 for server 2012 r2. Of course I click on the windows server 2012 r2 download link and a separate window pops-up. Well the download link is not there it's showing an 8.1 version, but above it's stating security update for windows server 2012 r2. So, if it's coming up with an alternative does this mean that update is no longer available for server 2012 r2?

Comment: What's the KB number?

Comment: Some of those updates require other updates, etc. before they will install so knowing the KB is important for a server person here to help you decipher what may be going on. I'd ensure Nessus is updated too on it's reporting modules and such in case it's looking for something on the OS that's no longer applicable.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for your response. So, the specific update I am talking about 
KB4025336 which is quite old from 2017. It's a quality rollup, but as I was stating previously I take it the update is no longer available? I am just wondering IF some other update supercede's it?

Comment: Windows monthly updates are always cumulative. If you install the update for this month (August 2023), it includes all previous updates and fixes. Even if the 2017 update is available, it should not be installed.

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you!

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 is derived from the Windows 8.1 codebase. That's why the update download name is windows8.1-kbxxxxxxx

Comment: @GregAskew Windows Server 2012 R2 only implemented cumulative updates at some point as far as I know?

Comment: @David Trevor: cumulative updates for Windows 2012 R2 began in April 2014 with KB2919355.